# Why so little current through bypass capacitor?

Tags: ac, bypass-capacitor

20V going into NMOS enhancment BSB012N03LX3 FET, gate is completely DC offset sinewave. Capacitor C1 does yeild AC only @ ~180nA - how would I go about making higher currents with this or a similar topology?

[image]

Comment: Why did you expect anything different to happen? The mosfet is not properly biased.

Comment: You are not opening the gate. You need voltage across gate-source, not gate-ground.

Answer (score 1):

the only current there is the current flowing through the mosfet gate capacitance.

You need to complete a DC circuit with the mosfet if you want to see amplification, currently the capacitor is blocking that DC circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems lite it would work but only with a resistor which imitates a short circuit to ground, normally a few mills is enough.[image]

Comment: Why would the equivalent of a shorted output give more current? Why would a MOS that's not properly biased work in a linear region which is far thinner than the driving signal? And what is the purpose of the circuit?